# Библиотека SimpleXLSX не может прочитать файл на другом сайте

Tags: php, simplexlsx

Юзаю библиотеку: SimpleXLSX

Указываю доступ к xlxs файлу на другом сайте

```
//подключение библиотеки
require_once __DIR__ . '/../simple-xlsx/simplexlsx.class.php'; 

// Файл xlsx
$xlsx = new SimpleXLSX('http://site.ru/catalog_crm.xlsx');
print_r($xlsx);
```

выдаёт, ошибку:

> SimpleXLSX Object ( [workbook_cell_formats] => Array ( )
>   [datetime_format] => Y-m-d H:i:s [workbook:SimpleXLSX:private] =>
>   [sheets:SimpleXLSX:private] => Array ( ) [styles:SimpleXLSX:private]
>   => [hyperlinks:SimpleXLSX:private] => [package:SimpleXLSX:private] => Array ( [filename] => [mtime] => 0 [size] => 0 [comment] => [entries]
>   => Array ( ) ) [datasec:SimpleXLSX:private] => Array ( ) [sharedstrings:SimpleXLSX:private] => [error:SimpleXLSX:private] =>
>   File not found http://site.ru/catalog_crm.xlsx
>   [debug:SimpleXLSX:private] => ) okSimpleXLSX Object (
>   [workbook_cell_formats] => Array ( ) [datetime_format] => Y-m-d H:i:s
>   [workbook:SimpleXLSX:private] => [sheets:SimpleXLSX:private] => Array
>   ( ) [styles:SimpleXLSX:private] => [hyperlinks:SimpleXLSX:private] =>
>   [package:SimpleXLSX:private] => Array ( [filename] => [mtime] => 0
>   [size] => 0 [comment] => [entries] => Array ( ) )
>   [datasec:SimpleXLSX:private] => Array ( )
>   [sharedstrings:SimpleXLSX:private] => [error:SimpleXLSX:private] =>
>   File not found http://site.ru/catalog_crm.xlsx
>   [debug:SimpleXLSX:private] => )

Если в качестве пути, указываю локальный путь к тому же файлу, то всё ок, в переменную $xlsx помещается массив с данными:

```
$xlsx = new SimpleXLSX(__DIR__ . '/excel_files/catalog_crm.xlsx');
```

Почему библиотека не может считать файл?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того чтоб с помощью этой библиотеки работать со сторонним файлом нужно вызвать другой метод и через file_get_contents():

```
$xlsx = SimpleXLSX::parseData( file_get_contents( 'http://site.ru/catalog_crm.xlsx') );
```

Comment: Выдаёт ошибку: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'parseData' (T_STRING), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE)

Подключал эту библиотеку: https://github.com/shuchkin/simplexlsx

Comment: вот пример из документации к этой библиотеки: `$xlsx = SimpleXLSX::parseData( file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/example.xlsx') )` . у вас ошибка синтаксиса, проверьте правильность написания. Я проверял этот метод, все работает нормально для сторонних ресурсов

Comment: разобрался, в этой библиотеке new не нужно писать